# Dotfile version control: terminal settings

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, dotfiles

I use one MacBook at home and another at work. Recently I started version controlling my dotfiles. It works like a dream for my vim/MacVim settings, but is decidedly less useful for my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

For instance, at home I have several aliases for accessing common folders or applications (which I don't have on my work machine), while at work I have to configure the proxy network.

I'm just wondering whether there is any 'natural' (or at least commonly-used) dotfile setup which separates machine-agnostic settings (which I want to place under version control) from machine-specific settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the machine-specific settings in a separate dot-file, e.g. `.bashrc-local`, while the common settings are in `.bashrc`. `.bashrc` would then contain:

```
test -e ~/.bashrc-local && source ~/.bashrc-local
```